# Xcode 13 missing products folder, where is the "Show Build Folder" in Finder menu

Tags: xcode, xcode13

The Xcode 13 release notes state that:

> The project navigator hides the Products group when it’s in the
> default location. The Product > Show Build Folder in Finder menu item
> replaces the most common use. (71561549)

Where is this menu? I'm on OSX 11.5.1 and running xcode13 but can't see anything in finder, or in the Xcode products dropdown menu. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What kind of project is this? Have you ever done a build?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can see the option on Xcode 13.0:

[image]

My Xcode version:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your screenshot. We both have the exact same version of Xcode. Perhaps it's because my OS is not at the most recent version. I'm on 11.5.1 when 11.6 is available.

Comment: Yes. I'm on macOS 11.6. It's interesting that a different OS version can change the functions of Xcode.

Comment: Why would Xcode 13 remove product folder in project navigator? Perhaps, project looks now much less messy, but it was essential when build and drag to simulator or device.

Comment: https://antbelousov.medium.com/how-to-return-products-folder-to-xcode-project-3ceb81782b2d